# JNI: Is GetIntArrayElements always linear in time?

Tags: java, c, performance, java-native-interface, time-complexity

Since I want to know whether it is worth it to use `JNI` to improve the performance of my application, I wanted to know what the complexity of `GetIntArrayElements` is. Does it always allocate a new primitive array in `C` and copy all the elements from the original `Java` array, or it somehow manages to pass a pointer?

I want to find out if it's worth it to use `JNI` for algorithms that are linear, e.g. pointwise multiplication of two vectors. In case `GetIntArrayElements` is linear, I guess the potential performance boost from using `C/C++` would be lost if we need to copy the vectors first.

Comment: You could pass a direct bytebuffer, which acts more or less like a pointer. But I doubt you'd gain much from using JNI. Oracle's JVM has a JIT, which emits highly optimized native code. And if there were any performance benefit, it would probably not amortize the cost of interop. JNI is mostly useful for when you have something that you can do in C, but can't do in Java, for instance OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

Would you mind sharing more about bytebuffers? (a link would suffice)

Moreover, does your comment imply that `GetIntArrayElements` is always linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetIntArrayElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Get_PrimitiveType_ArrayElements_routines) has an optional by-reference parameter called `isCopy`. When the VM makes a copy of the data for you to use, this parameter will be set to `JNI_TRUE`. The idea is that different VM implementations might have different memory representations of an array, also one that is not compatible with the memory layout that C expects.

Usually the fastest way of sharing memory between Java and native code is by using direct [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)s (ones that are created with `allocateDirect`). These buffers use an underlying block of memory that is directly usable from C/C++.

In Java you create a buffer and fill it with some data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] ba = "Hello Wolrd!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ba.length + 1); // for terminator
    bb.put(ba);
    callCPP(bb);
}

private static native void callCPP(ByteBuffer bytes);
```

And then from C/C++ you can get the address of the underlying block of bytes with [`GetDirectBufferAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress) (this is in C++):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_callCPP(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jobject buff) {
    const char* str = (char*) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(buff);
    printf(str); // Hello World!
}
```

The downside of using a `ByteBuffer` is that there is no data abstraction, like a class' field has a specific type, a position in the byte buffer does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The `isCopy` part alone answers my original question.

New question out of curiosity: Can you modify stuff in the native `C` implementation that will be visible in `Java` using the `ByteBuffer` approach?

Comment: @IvayloToskov It should work (that's the whole idea), and I just tried it, and yes!. :)